# use perl to repeat a line fixed no. of times

Tags: shell, perl, scripting

I have a file and i want to repeat some a fixed no. of line below it two times  and also to add a loop command just after the second line and end the loop after the second line ends.
so my file is

```
a4 b2 c3 e6
a1 b2 c3 d4
g5 h6 i7 j8
h9 i10 j11 k12
```

this should become

```
a4 b2 c3 e6
a1 b2 c3 d4
a1 b2 c3 d4
a1 b2 c3 d4
loop
g5 h6 i7 j8
endloop
h9 i10 j11 k12
```

I have to do this for 16 files .I am trying to use sed command but it is not working.I am figuring it how to do using perl?

I was trying to use perl -ne 'print $_ x 3' file but it operates on all the lines present in file.

/*edit suggested by ikegami*/

Comment: What problem you are having?

Comment: I was trying to use perl -ne 'print $_ x 3' file but it operates on all the lines present in file.

Comment: This is something that should have been in your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
perl -wpe'if ($.==2) { $_ x= 3 } elsif ($.==3) { $_ = "loop\n${_}endloop\n" }' <infile >outfile
```

or to change multiple files in place:

```
perl -i -wpe'close ARGV if eof; if ($.==2) { $_ x= 3 } elsif ($.==3) { $_ = "loop\n${_}endloop\n" }' file1 file2 file3
```

(the close is necessary to restart `$.`'s line count)

Answer (score 0):

Try this piece of code. It may solve your problem:

```
for (my $i = 0; <>; $i++) {
        print;
        if ($i == 1) {
                print;
                print;
                print "loop\n";
        } elsif ($i == 2) {
                print "endloop\n";
        }       
}
```